# Why is the following code showing segmentation fault whenever I input parantheses in the expression?

Tags: c

The code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define MAX 100

typedef struct stack
{
    char data[MAX];
    int top;
}stack;

void push(stack *s, char c)
{
    s->top++;
    if(s->top>MAX)
    {
        printf("Stack Overflow\n");
        return;
    }
    s->data[s->top]=c;

}

int isEmpty(stack *s)
{
    if(s->top==-1)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

int priority(char c)
{
    if(c=='(' || c==')')
        return 0;
    else if(c=='+' || c=='-')
        return 1;
    else if(c=='*' || c=='/')
        return 2;
    else if(c=='^')
        return 3;
}

void pop(stack *s)
{
    printf("%c ", s->data[s->top]);
    s->top--;
}

void infixToPostfix(stack *s)
{
    int c;
    printf("Enter an expression\n");
    while((c=getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if(isalnum(c))
            printf("%c ", c);
        else
        {
            if(c=='(')
                push(s, c);
            else if(c==')')
            {
                while(c != '(')
                    pop(s);
                pop(s);
            }
            else
            {
                 while((priority(c) <= priority(s->data[s->top])) && isEmpty(s))
                 {
                     pop(s);
                 }
                 push(s, c);
            }
        }
    }
    while(s->top)
    {
        pop(s);
    }
    pop(s);
}

int main(void)
{
    stack s;
    s.top=-1;
    infixToPostfix(&s);
    return 0;
}
```

For some odd reason, whenever there is a parantheses in the input expression, I get a segmentation fault. 
My aim was to convert an infix expression to a postfix expression. I was trying to implement it using a stack.

Is it because I am passing the stack from a called function to other functions?

Comment: Use a debugger, this way it's to hard to know!

Comment: `(priority(c) <= priority(s->data[s->top])) && isEmpty(s)` should be `isEmpty(s) && (priority(c) <= priority(s->data[s->top]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        else if(c==')')
        {
            while(c != '(')
                pop(s);
            pop(s);
        }
```

If `c` is a `)`, it can't be a `(` until you change its value. Inside that `while` loop, you don't change its value. So that will keep calling `pop` forever.

```
void pop(stack *s)
{
    printf("%c ", s->data[s->top]);
    s->top--;
}
```

This function has no safeties. If you `pop` when the stack is empty, it will read outside the bounds of `s->data`. So calling `pop` in an endless loop is a disaster.